# Mediaelement Fullscreen Flash Fallback does not scale in IE7 or IE8

Tags: jquery, html, video, html5-video, mediaelement.js

I have a video slide player I developed using MediaElement JS and some custom jQuery.

Everything about the player works great and does exactly what I needed it to do, except for one thing.

When in IE7 and IE8 it uses the flash fallback, whenever it uses the flash fallback it still goes full screen, however the video does not scale. It just stays the same dimensions and gets a big black background.

This is really a problem because the full screen feature is important to read some of the text on the video. Has anyone run into this before?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<video id="slide-video" src="/Slides/1.mp4" controls="controls" width="565" height="425">
  <object width="565" height="425" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/js/flashmediaelement.swf">
    <param name="movie" value="/js/flashmediaelement.swf" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="controls=true&amp;file=/Slides/1." />
  </object>
</video>
```

And here is the JavaScript I'm using

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();

var autoPlay = true;
var currChapter = 1;
var currSlide = 1;
var player;

$(document).ready(function () {
    player = new MediaElementPlayer('#slide-video', {
        plugins: ['flash'],
        pluginPath: '<%=SkinPath %>MediaElement/',
        flashName: 'flashmediaelement.swf',
        success: function (mediaElement, domObject) {
            // add event listener
            mediaElement.addEventListener('ended', videoEnded, false);

            if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version != '9.0' || $.browser.mozilla) {
                if (autoPlay)
                    loadSlide(1, 1);
            }
        }
    });

    $('ul.chapter li img').bind('click', function () {
        loadSlide($(this).attr('chapter'), $(this).attr('slide'));
    });

    if (!$.browser.msie && !$.browser.mozilla || $.browser.msie && $.browser.version == '9.0') {
        if (autoPlay) {
            loadSlide(1, 1);
        }
    }
});

function videoEnded() {
    var nextSlide = parseInt(currSlide) + 1;

    if ($('img[chapter=' + currChapter + '][slide=' + nextSlide + ']').length == 0) {
        currChapter++;
        //nextSlide = 1;
    }

    currSlide++;

    if ($('img[chapter=' + currChapter + '][slide=' + nextSlide + ']').length > 0) {
        loadSlide(currChapter, nextSlide);
    }
}

function videoPrev() {
    var nextSlide = parseInt(currSlide) - 1;

    if ($('img[chapter=' + currChapter + '][slide=' + nextSlide + ']').length == 0) {
        currChapter--;
        //nextSlide = 1;
    }

    currSlide--;

    if ($('img[chapter=' + currChapter + '][slide=' + nextSlide + ']').length > 0) {
        loadSlide(currChapter, nextSlide);
    }
}

function loadSlide(chapter,slide) {
    currChapter = chapter;
    currSlide = slide;

    $('.current-slide').text(slide);

    $('.slide-text-wrap div[slide]').hide();
    $('div[slide=' + slide + '].slide-text').show();

    var imageFile = $('img[chapter=' + chapter + '][slide=' + slide + ']').attr('src').replace('-thumb', '');

    $('.slide-img img:first').attr('src', imageFile);

    player.setSrc(imageFile.replace('.png', '.mp4'));
    player.play();
}
```

It works on other instances of the player I've seen. I'm using all the standard JS and CSS files beyond that.